# Bind list value in ArangoDB query

Tags: arangodb

I'm facing some issues when trying to bind a list variable in an ArangoDB query. More concretely, the list might look like as follows and comes from a URL parameter in a certain Foxx controller endpoint:

```
.../someAPIEndpoint?list=A,B,C,D
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
stmt = db._createStatement({query: "for i in [@list] return i"});
stmt.bind('list', req.params('list').split(','));
```

Since I do not know how many values will I receive from the API call, I can't create n bindings for each possible one. Is what I want to achieve even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were almost there, you can bind an array directly to the parameter (i just removed "[" and "]" from your query:

```
stmt = db._createStatement({query: "for i in @list return i"});
stmt.bind('list', req.params('list').split(','));
```

Comment: Hi @mchacki, thanks for your quick reply. I also tried that way, but I get ```ERROR A runtime error occurred while executing an action: [ArangoError 1563: list expected] Error: list expected```. Is there out any way to check what AQL query is actually being tried to be executed? I checked the ```stmt```object but bindings are not interpolated.

Comment: you could use  `stmt.explain()` to get some information about your query. Look for something like:
{
    "id" : 1,
    "loopLevel" : 1,
    "type" : "for",
    "resultVariable" : "i",
    "expression" : {
      "type" : "const value",
      "value" : "\"A,B,C,D\""
    }
  },
in this case i have bound a string instead of an array to @list